# Is it grammatically correct to say, "She is never worn lipstick to the pool before"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, prepositions

I was watching a movie and I heard that the actress said, "She **is** never worn lipstick **to** the pool before," I think it should be like this, "She **has** never worn lipstick **in** the pool before."

Is it grammatically correct to say, "She is never worn lipstick to the pool before"?

And is it correct to say, "She has never worn lipstick **to** the pool before"?

It is confusing for me to know whether "to the pool" is correct or "in the pool."

[Video](https://youtu.be/JtMc-ce4PLU)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on misunderstanding a contraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote is "***She's** never worn...*" not, "She is...".

"She's" can also be a contraction of "she is", but the context tells you which it is, and clearly it's "she has" in this case.

If she wears lipstick **to** the pool, that means between her house and the pool she's got lipstick on. She may remove it before she actually goes swimming.

If she wears lipstick **in** the pool, that means she goes swimming with lipstick on.

Comment: I understand, but is it correct to use "to" and "in" interchangeably in the mentioned context?

Comment: @dan I've added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

to wear lipstick in the pool [in the actual pool]

to wear lipstick to the pool [at the location of the pool but not in the water per se; on the occasion of going to the pool]

The second would not be usual but is not wrong if that is your meaning.

to wear a dress to the party [on the occasion of, like the two below]
to wear lipstick to the party
to wear sneakers to work or to school

The pronoun to and in have different meanings.

About the verb wear:
She **has worn** sneakers to school.
She **is wearing** sneakers to school today.

"She has worn" contracts to: "She's worn", which is has, not is.

Comment: But if you use "to" in the infinitive form of a verb and "for" followed by a noun, so "pool" is a noun, then why didn't the actress say, "for the pool"?

Comment: @dan Please write that out in full. It is very annoying to try and figure out cryptic remarks. Thank you.

Comment: @dan, it is not clear what you are asking, but I think you're assuming that there is something wrong with using _to_ twice, for different purposes. There isn't. Style guides sometimes advise finding ways to avoid repeating words, but a) that's a matter of style, not grammar, and b) it wouldn't apply here. You can wear something _for_ something only if you are referring to an event or activity ("wear an apron for cooking"). Sometimes you can use a place metonymically to represent an activity that happens there ("wear a suit for the office").